# MongoDB - Most Recent 20 unique

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to get the most recent unique value from a collection in MongoDB, however, the $group seems to be breaking the $sort somehow. Ie, in this case, im trying to get the most recent activity for a user (but only returning 20 activities total).

```
db.activities.aggregate([{ $sort: { timestamp:-1, firstname: 1 } }, { $limit: 20 }])
```

If i run the above, i get 20 results back and in the correct order, however, i have multiple doduments with the same firstname as the user has submitted multiple activities.

If i run the below, the top user from the first query is no longer in the list.  I get a completely different set of people back.

```
db.activities.aggregate([{ $sort: { timestamp:-1, firstname: 1 } },  { $group: { _id: "$firstname"} } , { $limit: 20 }])
```

How can i get the most recent activity per person, but limiting it to only 20 activities?

Comment: just sort after the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first find unique values, then apply limit and in the end just sort however you want. Its your solution with right ordering:

```
db.activities.aggregate([  
     { $group: { _id: "$firstname"} } , 
     { $limit: 20 },
     { $sort: { timestamp:-1, firstname: 1 } },
])
```

**Edit**: Above code will not return correct result because from [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) `$group` doesn't respect ordering. Instead you should `$sort` them before selecting first 20 like this:

```
db.activities.aggregate([  
     { $group: { _id: "$firstname"} } ,
     { $sort: { timestamp:-1, firstname: 1 } },
     { $limit: 20 },
])
```

This will return **unique** docs but if you need only **recent** docs without `unique` constraint then just remove the `$group` stage as its redundant and will consume performance exponentially. If you still need `unique` docs with better performance then you need to make time-related decision i.e. `$match` the docs greater than last 1 hour, `$group` them, `$sort` and `$limit` first 20.

Comment: How does this affect performance, in my example the collection in question has gained 11,000 records in a week (and its going to exponentially increased as it gets more popular). 

Also, as each person is doing an activity, i want the details of the most recent activity.   If i group them first does that not limit my ability to get the most recent activity as ill just get whatever was first?